# Cannot add references in the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using legacy assemblies in metro style app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722868/using-legacy-assemblies-in-metro-style-app)

I have downloaded and installed Windows 8 Developer preview with developer tools. I have a C# Metro Style app in my Visual Studio but I cannot add any reference to .Net assemblies on my project. For instance I cannot add any reference to `System.Security` assembly. I downloaded and installed the Ultimate version of the Visual Studio but nothing... How can I add reference to .Net assemblies? Thanks.

Comment: already checked this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722868/using-legacy-assemblies-in-metro-style-app and http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jeffreyr/archive/2011/09/20/core-net-types-usable-from-a-metro-style-application.aspx ?

Comment: Well the first one is for 3rd party libraries and the second one is not that related (it is but not that much) to my question. So I guess that it's not possible to do this in MetroStyle apps?

Comment: You are targeting a very limited subset of the .NET framework, the kind that can be expected to be supported on some future tablet running on an ARM core.  Called .NET APIs for Metro apps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it can't be done. Please read the comments on the question.