# Referencing Assemblies in Metro/JavaScript Application

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

How do you reference a regular .NET assembly in a class library project in a Metro app?

I am trying to create a mail interface in the class library project for a Metro JavaScript application, but the Visual Studio 11 default references don't include references to namespaces like System.Net.Mail, for instance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craig, check out this post:
http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jeffreyr/archive/2011/09/20/core-net-types-usable-from-a-metro-style-application.aspx

Also relevant are these:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301(v=VS.85).aspx#KnowTheRules
and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722868/using-legacy-assemblies-in-metro-style-app](http://%20using%20legacy%20assemblies%20in%20metro%20style%20app).

Comment: It looks like the approved references are already there, but System.Net.Mail just isn't one of them.

Comment: I found a forum post where Tim Heuer confirmed this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/3d80b028-96a0-4347-b542-22058dc25b42/